# 3rd party dll throws arithmetic overflow exception intermittently

Tags: c#, wcf, dll

I have a windows service and a WCF service.

Both reference the same 3rd party dll.

The windows service processes data every time correctly.

The Wcf service intermittently throws an arithmetic overflow exception on the same data. The 3rd party dll throws the exception.

When I update the app pool settings that the service runs on to have Enable 32-bit Application to True, the exception never occurs.

Anyone have any thoughts on what might be going wrong here? I do not like this as a solution to the problem

I've contacted the vendor of the 3rd party dll but have yet to receive a response.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the signatures of the functions from the dll and how you call them from your app? 32-bit applications have different pointer size than 64-bit ones, so you have to use the corresponding library build. I suggest you to ask both x64 and x86 versions of the dll from the vendor.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. Turns out the issue was in the 3rd party dll. They have since provided me with an updated version including a fix for this issue.